What does onUpdate: false parameter to the #[Validate] attribute in Livewire do?
I have the below in my code and having the onUpdate method to false has no different effect on the fronted when I submit a form. What does setting the parameter to false do?
#[Validate('required | image | max:1024', onUpdate: false)]


   public function store()
    {
        $this->validate();

       //Logic to create a post
    }


The parameter onUpdate set to false disables automatic validation and the properties must be validated explicitly using $this->validate() or $this->validateOnly()
For example:
<div>

    <div>

        <input type="text" wire:model.blur="input1" placeholder="At least 5 chars">

        @error('input1')
            <div class="text-red-600">
                {{ $message }}
            </div>
        @enderror

    </div>

    <div>
        <button wire:click="doSubmit">
            [ Submit! ]
        </button>
    </div>

</div>

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;
use Livewire\Component;


class ValidateTest extends Component
{

    #[Validate('required|min:5', onUpdate: false)]
    public $input1 = '';


    public function doSubmit()
    {
        // if onUpdate was true (default) the following line wouldn't be necessary
        $this->validate();

        // -- here we can do something like insert or update
    }


    public function updated($inputName)
    {
        // -- since onUpdate is false, to allow the validation on blur we need to enable the following line
        // $this->validateOnly($inputName);
    }
}


